# How to divide by time Python

Tags: python

I want my program to calculate how many jobs it completes per minute.

Here is what the program already knows:

ORIGINAL_NUM_OF_TOTAL_JOBS = this is the number of jobs it was told to complete
NUM_OF_TOTAL_JOBS_REMAINING = This is the number of jobs remaining

```
 print "\nTime Elapsed:" 
            TIME_ELAPSED = datetime.now() - STARTTIME
            print TIME_ELAPSED
            JOBS_PER_MINUTE = ORIGINAL_NUM_OF_TOTAL_JOBS - NUM_OF_TOTAL_JOB_REMAINING / TIME_ELAPSED
            print "\nAttempts/minute: "
            print JOBS_PER_MINUTE
```

I know the logic isn't right above because I'm dividing by "time" and time doesnt neccessarily = per minute, but im stuck.

Output/Error Message from python

```
Time Elapsed:
0:00:00.146000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jlemming\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myscript.py\src\myscript.py", line 117, in <module>
    ATTEMPTS_PER_MINUTE = ORIGINAL_NUM_OF_TOTAL_ATTEMPTS - NUM_OF_TOTAL_ATTEMPTS / TIME_ELAPSED
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: *attempt something 100 times, it has already completed 50 / minute* should be 100 attemps / minute, 50 completed / minute  **not** attempts per minute : 50

Comment: no taesu, it has 100 attempts total, it completed 50 so far and a minute has passed then it should print "attempts per minute: 50" Sorry for the confusion

Comment: ... what? read what you wrote. 100 attempts per minute, 50 completed per minute.

Comment: This is just an example, in reality I want the program to print the status every time it makes an attempt, then prints how many per minute it has done. This 50/100 is just an example to explain the problem

Comment: well your example is very confusing, or the way you wrote it is.

Comment: Sorry, I have reworded it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIME_ELAPSED` is a `datetime.timedelta` object (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). It has the method `total_seconds()`. Divide that by 60 to get the time elapsed in minutes.

```
TIME_ELAPSED = datetime.now() - STARTTIME
minutes = TIME_ELAPSED.total_seconds() / 60.0
ATTEMPTS_PER_MINUTE = (ORIGINAL_NUM_OF_TOTAL_ATTEMPTS - NUM_OF_TOTAL_ATTEMPTS) / minutes
```